# Out-of-core custom binary file processing

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, binaryfiles, binary-data

The problem at hand is a batch of large (500GB-1TB) binary files representing continuous time-series of data, that each have header **and** footer. I've seen plenty of solutions, like `Dask`, or Python core `mmap`, or NumPy `memmap`, or the like, but none of them seem to deal with the footer inclusion problem. Not that I have noticed at least, maybe there is some trivial thing like a "file-size mask" that allows me to "ghost" last `N` bytes of each file.

My restrictions in file interaction are limited to `read-only` access, and I have them all available locally.

What I currently have written is an `io.open(filename, 'rb', buffering=0)` that iterates over a list of files, and manually moves the pointer after each read, and keeps track of pointer's location relatively to the file. When it reaches the point where the next read would get into footer, e.g. into the next file, there is a really ugly bit that splits the chunk into two smaller, often asymmetric, chunks, where the first is read, then file switch occurs, and then the next one is read.

I feel like I am reinventing the bicycle with that, and I would greatly appreciate any brainstorm-level suggestions. I'll gladly work out technical details on my own, once I know the direction I should head.

Comment: Did you consider using [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/)? e.g. transform your binary data (in a single sequential reading pass) into some carefully designed SQLite database... or maybe build an SQLite database containing *offsets* into your original binary file.

Comment: Not really, no. I'm mostly concerned with improving the reading process itself, as I can straightforwardly, algorithmically generate the offset list - which I already do now. My current solution works, it is just ugly as hell amd probably underperforming compared to average, not state-of-the-art, solutions. The raw data itself is need only until the first computational pass, results of which reduce the selection size by orders of magnitude.